How can I pass a hotkey to WebView2 using SendInput when my CDialog has focus?
My CDialog has a WebView2 browser control on it.

I can click into the browser control, press CTRL + U and the WebView2 control will display the page source.
I can right-click the browser control to show my own context menu and invoke View Page Source myself using SendInput.

The problem I am having is when the CDialog has focus at the time the user presses CTRL + U. I added an accelerator for for the hotkey and the associated WM_COMMAND event handler (OnViewPageSource) to the dialog:
void CFooDlg::OnViewPageSource()
{
    if (m_pWebBrowser != nullptr)
    {
        m_pWebBrowser->SetFocus();
        m_pWebBrowser->ViewPageSource();
    }
}

The above event handler is processed. Here are the definitions of the two methods that it calls in my browser class:
#pragma warning (suppress : 26434)
void CWebBrowser::SetFocus()
{
    CHECK_FAILURE(m_pImpl->m_webController->MoveFocus(COREWEBVIEW2_MOVE_FOCUS_REASON_PROGRAMMATIC));
}

void CWebBrowser::ViewPageSource()
{
    // Create an array of generic keyboard INPUT structures
    std::vector<INPUT> vIP(4);
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
    {
        vIP.at(n).type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        vIP.at(n).ki.wScan = 0;
        vIP.at(n).ki.time = 0;
        vIP.at(n).ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
        vIP.at(n).ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    }

    vIP.at(0).ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    vIP.at(1).ki.wVk = 'U';

    vIP.at(2).ki.wVk = 'U';
    vIP.at(2).ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    vIP.at(3).ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    vIP.at(3).ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

    SendInput(4, vIP.data(), sizeof(INPUT));
}

But nothing is happening. And when I type m_pImpl->m_webController-> in my IDE the method SendInput does not show up in the list. So I can't use SendInput from there.

I am confused because in this article it suggested:

To send input to the web page, we can use the SendInput method of the WebView2 object. This method takes a string of input events, such as keyboard events or mouse clicks, in JSON format.
webView->SendInput(L"{\"type\":\"keydown\", \"key\":\"Enter\"}");


That got me to thinking. In their sample code webView is defined as ICoreWebView2* webView. I have a similar variable. In my class I have a structure:
struct CWebBrowserImpl
{
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Environment>    m_webViewEnvironment;
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Environment2>   m_webViewEnvironment2;
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2>               m_webView;
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2_2>             m_webView2;
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2_11>            m_webView2_11;
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2_16>            m_webView2_16;
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller>     m_webController;
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Controller3>    m_webController3;
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2Settings>       m_webSettings;
};

So I went to try:
m_pImpl->m_webView->SendInput(4, vIP.data(), sizeof(INPUT));

But my version of ICoreWebView2 does not have SendInput.
